# How to debug and fix nginx wrong location redirection problem?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have an Nginx config file list below. I want to send the request to different server base on Refer.

When I send a request with URL "doamin.com/capi/a/b" and refer "a.com/a/1/test", everything is good, server "be" will get "be/a/b" request. 
But if I send a request with URL "doamin.com/capi/a/b" and refer "a.com/a/0/test", server "be_demo" will get "be_demo/" request, the path "a/b" is missing.

I've tried to add "/" at the end of "be_demo", it doesn't work.

```
map $http_referer $be_pool {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        default                  be;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        "~a\.com\/.*\/0\/.*"       be_demo;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    } 
    server {
        ...
        location ~ ^/capi/(.*)$ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            proxy_pass http://$be_pool/$1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        } 
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numeric capture `$1` is set by the last *regular expression* to be evaluated. In the second case, the regular expression in the `map` statement is evaluated **after** the regular expression in the `location` statement.

The solution is to use a named capture instead.

For example:

```
map $http_referer $be_pool {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    default                  be;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "~a\.com\/.*\/0\/.*"     be_demo;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
} 
server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/capi/(?<myuri>.*)$ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        proxy_pass http://$be_pool/$myuri;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    } 
}
```